# Coreplot periodic scaleToFit while Pinching

Tags: ios, plot, core-plot

I have a chart with unknown number of plots(line charts) on it. I periodically ask a server for new data for them. Then I use:

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace*)_graph.defaultPlotSpace;
[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:_graph.allPlots];
```

to fit all the plots, in the chart, rightafter reloading the new data into the plots.

The point is the chart is pinch-able and this cause a problem. e.g. where zoomed-out plots will suddenly gets back to fit position on reloading and refitting. Do you recommend any strategy to use scaleToFit a bit smarter?

Answer (score 0):

Save the old plot ranges (`xRange` and `yRange`) before calling `-scaleToFitPlots:`. Compare the before and after ranges and decide whether you want to keep the old zoomed range, the new scaled range, or something in between. For example, if the new range falls within the old range (check with `-containsRange:`), revert back to the old one.